# NSUrlConnection executing multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, ios7.1

I've uploaded a image using the below code.Image saving 3 times in Web server. I am confusing to make changes in my code.

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

```
 NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


   [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);

NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 if (connReq)
 {

    NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");
  //  receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

else {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}

[connReq start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your

`NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
  returningResponse:nil 
  error:nil];`

with `NSData *returnData;`

it'll reduce from 3 to 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing the request three times...

First with

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

then with

```
NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and finally with

```
[connReq start];
```

You should check the [NSURLConnection reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: hey @marcos crispino can u suggest me changes here.

Comment: Use only one of the three methods... If you need your request to be synchronous, use the sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: method. Or, if it may be asynchronous, use connectionWithRequest:delegate: and implement the delegate methods.

Comment: here the problem is i need to upload the data along with image so i'm using nsurl connection and request is synchronus. i've deleted [connReq start]; . bt still its uploading 3 times

Answer (score 2):

Finalised code for you to reduce for 1 image

```
 NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&AgeRange=%@",UserId,CategoryId,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,gender,imagename,ageTextfield.text];

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see why you're sending your data 2 of those 3 times. The call

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
  returningResponse:nil 
  error:nil];
```

is an NSURL class call that triggers the request. It's a class call, so you don't have to create an instance of NSURLConnection to use it.

I would advise against using it, because it's synchronous, and will block your app's UI until the request has been completed.

Later, you create an instance of NSURLConnection with the same URL Request and start the connection. That triggers another request, this one asynchronous.

You should delete the `sendSynchronousRequest:` call.

I don't know why you're uploading a 3rd copy of the file however.

Edit: By the way, you are creating JPEG data for your image, but sending a content type of image/png. That mismatch will probably cause a problem on the server side, or if another client attempts to download and use the image that you're uploading.

Comment: hi @Duncan C, Thanx for the Answer:),if you don't mind Pleaes suggest the changes here.

Comment: Step 1. Delete the line that calls sendSynchronousRequest. Step 2. Change the mime type of your upload to "image/jpeg". Step 3: Delete the line `[connReq start]`. @MarcosCrispino pointed out that the connectionWithRequest method starts running the request, something I had forgotten.